# Need help in parsing XML having innertexts

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I want to parse XMLs having multiple innertext.

```
<tag>
Outertext_before a tag
<innertag_1> innercontent </innertag_1>
Outertext_after inner tag 1
<innertag_2> innercontent </innertag_2>
Outertext_after inner tag 2
</tag>
```

Expected Output:

```
PARENT_TAG  PRESENT_TAG SERIALNUMBER_FROM_PARENT    CONTENT

tag,    tag,        1,  Outertext_before a tag
tag,    innertag_1, 2,  innercontent
tag,    tag,        3,  Outertext_after inner tag 1
tag,    innertag_2, 4,  innercontent
tag,    tag,        5,  Outertext_after inner tag 2
```

How to parse XMLs having innertext. 
I tried using lxml.etree but I am failing to parse sequentially.

Comment: "I am failing to parse sequentially". How? Please show us your code. Perhaps you are not aware of the [`tail`](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#elements-contain-text) property.

Comment: tail() solves my requirement.
Thanks @mzjn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Using tail() in lxml , I have retrieved the innertext content.